# DRF nested-relationships : models relations

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Assuming I have a model classes as,

```
class Estudiante(models.Model): 
    nombre = models.CharField(..)
    ...

class Invitado(models.Model): 
    invitadoi =  models.ForeignKey(Estudiante)    
    ...


class Respuesta(models.Model): 
    nombrer = models.ForeignKey(Invitado, related_name="invitado")  
    ...
```

How can I create a `Respuesta` serializer and get `nombre` field of `Estudiante` model in the json result?

Comment: You want to use a `serializers.SerializermethodField()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **`source='nombrer.invitadoi.nombre'`** in your serializer as,

```
class RespuestaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nombre = serializers.CharField(source='nombrer.invitadoi.nombre')

    class Meta:
        fields = ('nombre',)  # other fields
        model = Respuesta
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
class RespuestaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     nombre_estudiante = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     def get_nombre_estudiante(self, obj):
        if obj.nombrer and obj.nombrer.invitadoi:
            return obj.nombrer.invitadoi.nombre

    class Meta:
        model = Respuesta
        fields = ['nombre_estudiante']
```